# Как сделать исключение в проверки текстбоксов на пустоту

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть метод который проверяет все TextBox'ы на пустую строку

```
private bool CheckIsEmptyBoxs() => 
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)) ? true : false;
```

На форме есть много Текстбоксов, мне нужно сделать исключение чтобы не проверяло отдельный текстбокс от всех остальных, как сделать обход отдельного текстбокса с методом `CheckIsEmptyBoxs` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool CheckIsEmptyBoxs() =>   
  this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().
  Except(new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2 }).
  Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)) ? true : false;
```